# Cursor performance improvement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following cursor defined:

```
DECLARE cursor1 FOR 
    SELECT BR1, REFNO1, STRTDTE, ENDDTE, PENAMT, ACCT, PRINAMT 
    FROM TBL1

--Temp variables are defined 
DECLARE @lBr1 CHAR(3), @lREFNO1 CHAR(20), @lSTRTDTE DATETIME;
DECLARE @lENDDTE DATETIME, @lACCT CHAR(35), @lPENAMT  FLOAT;
DECLARE @lPRINAMT FLOAT, @nSchdInt FLOAT

OPEN cursor1

FETCH cursor1 INTO @lBr1, @lDealNo1, @lSTRTDTE, @lENDDTE, @lACCT, @lPENAMT, @lPRINAMT

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @nSchdIntAmt = AMT 
    FROM 
        TBL2 
    WHERE
        REFNO1 = @lREFNO1
        AND STRTDTE = @lSTRTDTE 
        AND ENDDTE = @lENDDTE

    --IF THERE IS NO RECORD
    IF @@rowcount = 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TBL2
            SELECT * FROM TBL1 
    END

    --If record present update following columns
    ELSE
    BEGIN  
        UPDATE TBL2 
        SET PRINAMT = @nSchdIntAmt,
            PENAMT = @lPENAMT 
        WHERE
            DEALNO = @lREFNO1  
            AND BR1 = @lBr1
    END 

 ---Fetch next rows
```

This cursor is processing 50K rows and taking 25 -30 min. I tried to provide indexing while column selection from TBL1 for performance improvement but no luck. Any other way to implement it?

Comment: Hint:  Learn about `MERGE`.

Comment: You define a cursor on `TBL1`, then every time a single record does not match, you insert _all_ of `TBL1` into `TBL2`???? There's no reason to use a cursor for this, and I don't think you've sanitised this properly

Comment: The way to improve performance here is to stop using a cursor. You need to do this type of thing with a set based approach, not RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: To Nick, I check TBL1 data is present in TBL2 or not? If not insert row, if present Update PRINAMT =  @nSchdIntAmt and thats why cursor is my first option.

Comment: @Learner Nope. Nick is spot on. There is no point in "improving performance" when your logic has major errors. Your insert statement will insert **ALL** rows in TBL1 into TBL2 - not the "current" row retrieved by your cursor. In addition, you use lREFNO1 in your select and update statements of TBL2 but it is never set to any value. You also use multiple undeclared local variables (e.g., lDealNo1) so the script won't even compile.